# How do i declare a field on a table with the datatype of Medium Blob in EF Code First

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Im using dotnet Core EntityFramework using SapientGuardian.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

I have a database Entity with a property called ProfileImage stored as a `byte[]` ... extract below

```
public class ProfileEntity
{

    /// Gets or sets the full name.
    /// </summary>
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// A Byte Array with the profile image Bitmap
    /// </summary>
    public byte[] ProfileImage { get; set; }
}
```

When this get created in the MySql Database it creates a BLOB DataType.

My Question is how can set it to be a MediumBlob?

**Edit:**
The Migration (which I forgot to run) produced the following:

```
public partial class AddMediumBlob : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<byte[]>(
            name: "ProfileImage",
            table: "ProfileEntity",
            type: "MediumBlob",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(byte[]),
            oldNullable: true);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<byte[]>(
            name: "ProfileImage",
            table: "ProfileEntity",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(byte[]),
            oldType: "MediumBlob",
            oldNullable: true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Fluent API in your DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProfileEntity>().Property(p => p.ProfileImage)
        .HasColumnType("MediumBlob");
}
```

Comment: I have just tried that an it doesn't seem to work. It still keeps it as a Blob. Does the fact that I am using dotnet Core EF make any difference?

Comment: Did you create a new migration? If yes, can you post the created migration class?

Comment: Opps I forgot the Migration

Comment: It is still not updating the database after running the migration. I am doing a drop and recreate and I can see that the migration has been run on the __EFMigrationsHistory Table but the data type is still BLOB

Comment: Maybe that's an EF bug that it doesn't recognize to update the table. If you are already dropping and recreating the database, can you please also try to delete all migrations and then create a new one?

Comment: Thanks @Raphael: That seems to have resolved it. The initial migration script had it as b.Property<byte[]>("ProfileImage").HasColumnType("MEDIUMBLOB"); in capitals